# Django Migrations; maintaining admin database concurrency with collaborators

Tags: python, django

I have two databases for my Django app. One is intended for tracking user information using django's admin, auth et cetera. The other is for my app. When I makemigrations for the scripts app it is fine, creates migrations in migrations folder and whatnot, but if I makemigrations for the default database, where are those stored? I was going to version control these migrations so that collaborators could sync up with me as we go. Am I doing this all wrong? Django version is 1.9

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': os.environ.get("PSQL_AUTH",''), # set in .bashrc
        'USER': os.environ.get("PSQL_USER",''), # set in .bashrc
        'PASSWORD': os.environ.get("PSQL_PW", ''),
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '5432',
    },
    'scripts': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': os.environ.get("PSQL_SCRIPTS",''), # set in .bashrc 
        'USER': os.environ.get("PSQL_USER",''),
        'PASSWORD': os.environ.get("PSQL_PW", ''),
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: turns out the django migrations for auth, admin, contenttype, sessions are stored in the installation location of Django. I tried using 'MIGRATION_MODULES' setting to write the migrations being performed on those apps to my project folder but no dice.

Comment: @e4c5 There are 4 other apps to be set up in the same project using different databases.This is the first of a few. It makes sense to segregate the data.

Comment: @e4c5 These apps function independently. One app does not need to reference data in another app. Pretty sure with my use case I will be able to manage without joining tables across databases, but the question isn't "how do i perform a join of a user table with the table of another database?"

Comment: @e4c5 as i said, that is not the question.

Answer (score 0):

You could use **django db routers**

https://djangosteps.wordpress.com/2011/11/08/multiple-database-implementation-in-django/

```
class MyApp2Router(object):
    """
    A router to control all database operations on models in
    the myapp2 application
    """

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        """
        Point all operations on myapp2 models to 'my_db_2'
        """
        if model._meta.app_label == 'myapp2':
            return 'my_db_2'
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        """
        Point all operations on myapp models to 'other'
        """
        if model._meta.app_label == 'myapp2':
            return 'my_db_2'
        return None

    def allow_syncdb(self, db, model):
        """
        Make sure the 'myapp2' app only appears on the 'other' db
        """
        if db == 'my_db_2':
            return model._meta.app_label == 'myapp2'
        elif model._meta.app_label == 'myapp2':
            return False
        return None
```

Comment: This does not answer the question about migrations for the Django authentication backend. This does not answer the question about maintaining concurrency of multiple users' separate databases.